# Undefined reference to vtable but method overriden

Tags: c++

I'm having an issue when compiling my program, it seems to be a problem that happened when we don't implement a virtual method, but in my case I have implemented it.

```
class Circle : public Viewable{
private:
    int _x,_y,_radius;
    Color *_color;
public:
    void draw();

    Circle(Viewport *v, int x, int y, int radius, Color *c) : Viewable(v) {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
        _radius = radius;
        _color = c;
    }
    ~Circle() {};
};
```

That class extends this one :

```
class Viewable {
protected:
   Viewport *viewport;
public:
    virtual void draw()=0;
    virtual ~Viewable(){};
    Viewable(Viewport*v)
    {
        viewport=v;
    }
};
```

And the problem is the following one :
undefined reference to 'vtable for Circle'

Here is the `.cpp` of `Circle`:

```
void Circle::draw(){
        int x0 = _radius, y0 = 0;
        int radiusError = 1 - x0;

        while (y0 <= x0) {
            viewport->SetPixel(x0 + _x, y0 + _y, *_color);
            viewport->SetPixel(y0 + _x, x0 + _y, *_color);
            viewport->SetPixel(-x0 + _x, y0 + _y, *_color);
            viewport->SetPixel(-y0 + _x, x0 + _y, *_color);
            viewport->SetPixel(-x0 + _x, -y0 + _y, *_color);
            viewport->SetPixel(-y0 + _x, -x0 + _y, *_color);
            viewport->SetPixel(x0 + _x, -y0 + _y, *_color);
            viewport->SetPixel(y0 + _x, -x0 + _y, *_color);
            y0++;

            if (radiusError < 0)
                radiusError += 2 * y0 + 1;

            else {
                x0--;
                radiusError += 2 * (y0 - x0 + 1);
            }

        }
```

Here is the log from clion :

```
====================[ Build | stpfonctionne | Debug ]===========================
/app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/samuel/Bureau/stpfonctionne/cmake-build-debug --target stpfonctionne -- -j 6
[ 33%] Linking CXX executable stpfonctionne
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/stpfonctionne.dir/main.cpp.o: attention: réadressage sur « _ZTV6Circle » dans la section en lecture seule « .text._ZN6CircleC2EP8ViewportS1_iiiP5Color[_ZN6CircleC5EP8ViewportS1_iiiP5Color] »
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld : CMakeFiles/stpfonctionne.dir/main.cpp.o : dans la fonction « Circle::Circle(Viewport*, Viewport*, int, int, int, Color*) » :
/home/samuel/Bureau/stpfonctionne/headers//circle.h:19 : référence indéfinie vers « vtable for Circle »
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: attention: création de DT_TEXTREL dans un PIE
collect2: erreur: ld a retourné le statut de sortie 1
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/stpfonctionne.dir/build.make:118 : stpfonctionne] Erreur 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95 : CMakeFiles/stpfonctionne.dir/all] Erreur 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:102 : CMakeFiles/stpfonctionne.dir/rule] Erreur 2
make: *** [Makefile:137 : stpfonctionne] Erreur 2
```

Comment: Have you implemented `Circle::draw()`? You've declared it in the class, but have you provided a definition for it?

Comment: The `Circle` class neither have a destructor nor (as we can see) a definition for `draw()`.

Comment: @SamuelT Can you add the definition here?

Comment: @acraig5075 Thanks for your answer, I edited with the full code.

Comment: Side note: Virtual classes should be provided a virtual destructor, otherwise you are unable to delete objects via pointer to base.

Comment: how do you compile it? Best would be if you include a tiny `main` with includes and a single line creating an instance and calling the function and explain how you compile the code. The code you did post looks ok

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I firstly tried to compile with g++, I thought it was a problem of linking. So I tried using the compiler of clion to rule out this possibility but the problem is persisting.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and provide that here, along with the full commandline used for compiling and the error message that produces. Odds are, you will find the error yourself that way.

Comment: i was not asking for which compiler, the effects should be the same. But how you compile it, you need to compile Circle.cpp and link it. I am just guessing, but thats a common mistake

Comment: @SamuelT The same example works [here](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/7fXNt8y).

Comment: @SamuelT Are you building any library to link your program ??

Comment: Please show your build log,

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I have add it, it's in french I hope it's understandable for you.

Comment: maybe the `Circle.cpp` isn't being linked? So there's no real implementation of a function for the linker

Comment: CLion usually is cmake based. Can you post the top-level ```CMakeLists.txt``` as well?
That reference to PIE in the warnings seems weird.

Comment: try compiling it with the compiler (g++ in your case)
maybe it'c cmake's fault for not compiling it properly
g++ -o 'exec_name' 'source_directory'/*.cpp -g

Comment: You only link main.cpp.o and not circle.cpp.o, chances are circle.cpp is not added to the project and is unused by cmake

Comment: The link error refers to this 6-parameter constructor: `Circle(Viewport*, Viewport*, int, int, int, Color*)` The constructor you declare has 5 parameters: `Circle(Viewport *v, int x, int y, int radius, Color *c)`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently some of you are right, it's a problem with the linking, some files were not in the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

`Circle::draw()` must not be virtual. Only the base class method should be virtual.
Same applies to the `Circle` destructor as well.
And virtual base class destructor should actually be declared as `virtual ~Viewable() = default;`

Comment: true, but it's still a bad thing to do

Comment: So this does not answer the question.

Comment: I thought it might've been. Now I've tried it, and it works, so yeah, not an answer. Feel free to downvote